# USB wireless Netgear adapter

Tags: drivers, wireless

I have just purchased a new Netgear N600 WIFI USB adapter for my desktop that currently runs ubuntu. I am new to ubuntu and still unfamiliar with it.
If anyone could help me get this set up on my computer I would greatly appreciate it.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0846:9011 NetGear, Inc. WNDA3100v2 802.11abgn [Broadcom BCM4323]
```

Comment: Enter `lsusb` in terminal and edit your question to add the results

Comment: Lots of usb wifi adapters will "just work" when you plug it in... does yours not work? Or are you looking for info how to use the GUI tools to find & connect to wifi networks?

Comment: yeah it wont connect by just hooking it up

Comment: when i do the command lsusb it says it uses broadcom bcm4323

Comment: We need all of the details of _lsusb_. bcm4323 is not enough.

Comment: @mchid I'd prefer to verify from jbarnet. If you are correct, the device 0846:9011 is driven by ndiswrapper and not bcmwl-kernel-source.

Comment: Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0846:9011 NetGear, Inc. WNDA3100v2 802.11abgn [Broadcom BCM4323]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 03f0:2003 Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 413c:2005 Dell Computer Corp. RT7D50 Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Broadcom USB wireless usually works with ndiswrapper. Please obtain a temporary internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible and open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-utils-1.9
```

Now download the files at post #6 here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2052594 Drag and drop the file to your desktop so we can find them. Right-click and select 'Extract Here.' Find out if your system is 32- or 64-bit:

```
arch
```

Now we install the driver files:

```
cd ~/Desktop/Broadcom_bcm43xx_USB_32_64bit_v2
```

If your system is 32-bit (i686), install the 32-bit driver file:

```
sudo ndiswrapper -i bcmn43xx32.inf
```

And if it is a 64-bit (x86_64) system:

```
sudo ndiswrapper -i bcmn43xx64.inf
```

In either case:

```
sudo ndiswrapper -ma
sudo depmod -a
sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: This is what came up

Comment: john@john-Dell-DV051:~/Desktop/Broadcom_bcm43xx_USB_32_64bit_v2$ sudo ndiswrapper -ma
module configuration information is stored in /etc/modprobe.d/ndiswrapper.conf
john@john-Dell-DV051:~/Desktop/Broadcom_bcm43xx_USB_32_64bit_v2$ sudo depmod -a

Comment: john@john-Dell-DV051:~/Desktop/Broadcom_bcm43xx_USB_32_64bit_v2$ sudo modprobe ndiswraper
modprobe: FATAL: Module ndiswraper not found.
john@john-Dell-DV051:~/Desktop/Broadcom_bcm43xx_USB_32_64bit_v2$

Comment: My apologies for the typo. Please try: sudo modprobe ndiswrapper. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Awesome! Sorry for my mis-step.

Answer (score -1):

Having viewed several Internet posts about how to get the Netgear WNDA3100v2  working in Linux, the only way I can make it authenticate with my EnGenius router is to downgrade the security in the router to WPA(TKIP). I decided I wasn't willing to use an obsolete security protocol to use the WNDA3100v2. Hopefully, in the not too distant future, a native Linux driver will be developed for the Broadcom BCM4323 chipset. FYI, I am running Debian with the MATE UI.

Comment: The OP certainly does not want to downgrade their security. I wouldn't