# Netgear N600 router not connecting to wifi - help!

Tags: networking, wireless, usb, netgear

I'm extremely new to linux and i'm looking into using linux because my windows trial is running out and I don't have the money to buy a copy. I've been running ubuntu off of a usb to try it out, but I hit a snag. I have a Netgear N600 Dual band usb adapter that isen't supported by the linux. 
 I followed the steps here : [USB wireless Netgear adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/568056/usb-wireless-netgear-adapter) - and it kinda of (?) worked. The light blinks but when I try connecting to my network (A list of networks appears) it'll stay orange, ask me for a password - start blinking blue and orange then once I click connect it'll completely turn off then the process will restart in a loop. The funny thing is if i try connecting to the hotspot on my phone it can connect, I'm at a loss here please help!Ethernet is not an option for where i'm at.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enter this in the terminal:

```
rfkill list up
lsmod wlan0 
nmap -v -iR google.com
```

and then make a script and run it might work this way:

```
#/bin/sh

 Case ![$] in
    ./bin/sh
    network=<ip adr here>
    gksu <ip adr here>
    nmcli Cl asleep=false
    resolvconf network >>
 endl
```

and it might work fine this way.