# How to Install WiFi (Netgear N600 Dual Band WNDA3100v3)

Tags: wireless, netgear

O/S is Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.  WiFi card is Netgear N600 Dual Band WNDA3100v3.  Wired network connection was used for the download and install.  Want to deactivate wired and install wireless in its place. None of the instructions I see so far solve my needs.  Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question an add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [USB wireless Netgear adapter](http://askubuntu.com/questions/568056/usb-wireless-netgear-adapter)

Comment: Have a look on this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/568118/214264

Answer (score 1):

If you ran the command `lsusb` and find that your device is 0846:9053, then your device is driven by a very new driver, mt7662u_sta. Please get a temporary internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210.git
cd Netgear-A6210
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe mt7662u_sta
```

According to the github page:

> This is work in progress. The driver is functional. However, there are
>   still several issues that need to be addressed. In particular,
>   hot-unplugging may cause the network manager to segfault. After
>   plugging the dongle back in, you may need to restart the manager:
>
> $ sudo service network-manager restart

Of course, you can avoid this by not plugging or unplugging the device unless the computer is shut off.

You have compiled the driver for your current kernel version only. When Update Manager installs a newer kernel version, also known as linux-image, after the requested reboot, recompile:

```
cd Netgear-A6210
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe mt7662u_sta
```

Please retain the file and these instructions for that time.

---

## Update

The repository above hasn't received an update since 2017. Upstream development of the software has apparently been moved to https://github.com/Netgear-A6210-linux-driver/Netgear-A6210. Hence, the current (April 2020, tested on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS + mt7662u_sta driver) instructions for installing the driver are:

```
git clone https://github.com/Netgear-A6210-linux-driver/Netgear-A6210.git
cd Netgear-A6210
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: @WadirLeoncio A great many solutions that are three or more years old are stale in 2020. That's just the nature of Ubuntu and Linux. Thanks, however, for the update.