# Netgear AC1200 WiFi USB Adapter, model A6150

Tags: drivers, netgear

I'm having a really hard time trying to find the drivers for the Netgear AC1200 WiFi USB Adapter, model A6150. I need it for Ubuntu 18.04. Please, help.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079377/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-realtek-rtl8812bu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [USB wireless Netgear adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/568056/usb-wireless-netgear-adapter)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install drivers for Realtek RTL8812BU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079377/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-realtek-rtl8812bu)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to install an AC1200 Wifi adapterfrom dootoper I bought from Amazon.
Got the driver from this github  https://github.com/gordboy/rtl8812au

This works every time I install it.. I did this a few times because of every time an update is installed the wifi adapter stops working.

I have an old wifi adapter which isn't that fast like the new one, so I switch sometimes to the old one.

I have this installed thru a usb extra cable to have a better signal same as the new one.

The cables are different: one is a usb3 highspeed extension cable, the other an old usb 2 extension cable.

The funny thing I now found out is, that the new AC1200 Wifi adapter always works with the old cable every time!

Comment: The repo you link is for the rtl8812au chipset, where as the A6150 has the rtl8812bu chipset. Are you sure that it will work despite this? Can you be more specific on the wifi adapter that you bought?